# Extracting Date from Text in SQL using cursor

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have data in a table like:

Table A:

```
ID  Text
2   This value is Nov 20 2020 and will be Jan 20 2021 
3   This value is Sep 20 2020 and will be Oct 20 2020, Nov 20 2020
```

Desired Output:

```
ID Date
2  Nov 20 2020
2  Jan 20 2021
3  Sep 20 2020
3  Oct 20 2020
3  Nov 20 2020
```

I am thinking that it will be done with a cursor but currently stuck since i have never used it.
I am using MS SQL Server

Any idea how this can be achieved?

Comment: I would suggest using a different language. SQL Server's string manipulation is far from good, and it does not natively support REGEX. Even if you *were* to use SQL, a `CURSOR` is one of the last way you should be doing this.

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't use any other language since the data is in SQL tables and i have to load it later into a table. The process has to be automated

Comment: Just because the data is in SQL (Server) doesn't mean you have to use SQL.

Comment: Can it also be assumed that the dates will ***always*** be in the format `MMM dd yyyy`? If not, then this further compounds SQL is the wrong language; in fact, if the format is not standardised I would then say that SQL is one of the *worst* languages to try to do this in.

Comment: Yes the dates will always be in the same format. Using cursor is just an idea on my mind.

Comment: Two questions: (1) will days have leading zeros (i.e. `Jan 01` vs `Jan 1`) and (2) can the same month occur multiple times in 1 Text value?

Comment: Yes the days will have leading zeros. Same Month can occur multiple times but the dates will be different. If they are same then it's a data error and can be ignored.

Comment: Is the format of the rest of the text _fixed_, e.g. the first date is always prefixed by "value is" and the second set of dates is always prefixed with "will be"? Have you considered storing this data more correctly in the first place? Also please tag with the version of SQL Server you're using. Solutions may be different for SQL Server 2000 vs. SQL Server 2019. Don't make us guess.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solutions only works based on *several assumptions* documented in the code.

**Sample data**

```
create table tableA
(
  ID int,
  Txt nvarchar(200)
);

insert into tableA (ID, Txt) values
(2, 'This value is Nov 20 2020 and will be Jan 20 2021'),
(3, 'This value is Sep 20 2020 and will be Oct 20 2020, Nov 20 2020');
```

**Solution 1**

Without (recursive) CTE or regular expressions.

```
-- assumes leading zeros for days (i.e. Jan 01)
-- assumes that a month will not occur multiple times within one Txt

select a.id,
       substring(a.Txt, charindex(m.Name, a.Txt), 11) as [Date]
from tableA a
join (values('Jan'), ('Feb'), ('Mar'), ('Apr'),
            ('May'), ('Jun'), ('Jul'), ('Aug'),
            ('Sep'), ('Oct'), ('Nov'), ('Dec')) m(Name) -- month names
  on charindex(m.Name, a.Txt) > 0;
```

See it in action: [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=2fb66b2a31d1230a5f146f5754ec0569).

**Solution 2**

Allows for repeated months (with a recursive CTE) and should be better at date detection (see Larnu's comment below).

```
-- assumes leading zeros for days
-- assumes that a month abbreviation will be between spaces

with cteMthNm as
(
  select m.Name
  from (values (' Jan '), (' Feb '), (' Mar '), (' Apr '),
               (' May '), (' Jun '), (' Jul '), (' Aug '),
               (' Sep '), (' Oct '), (' Nov '), (' Dec ')) m(Name)
),
cteCount as
(
  select a.id, a.Txt, 1 as Num, charindex(m.Name, a.Txt) as Pos, m.Name as Mth
  from tableA a
  cross join cteMthNm m
  where charindex(m.Name, a.Txt) > 0
    union all
  select c.id, c.Txt, c.Num+1, charindex(m.Name, c.Txt, c.Pos+3), m.Name
  from cteCount c
  cross join cteMthNm m
  where charindex(m.Name, c.Txt, c.Pos+3) > 0
    and m.Name = c.Mth
)
select c.id, c.Txt, substring(c.Txt, c.Pos+1, 11) as [Date]
from cteCount c
order by c.id;
```

New version: [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=897dfcf27a7bc4c9ad4481c75748b589).

Comment: An additional assumption is that the text never includes the abbreviation of the month elsewhere. For example the text "It was Declined on Dec 20 2020" would fail as well.

Comment: @Larnu, indeed! Makes the quest for a simple solution again a bit harder...

Comment: This worked for me. I did some modifications to suit my exact requirement.

Answer (score 4):

You can use a recursive CTE:

```
with cte as (
      select id, convert(varchar(max), null) as dte, convert(varchar(max), text) as rest, 0 as lev
      from t
      union all
      select id,
             left(stuff(rest,
                        1,
                        patindex('%[A-Z][a-z][a-z] [0-9][0-9] [0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]%', rest),
                        1), 11),
              stuff(rest,
                    1,
                    patindex('%[A-Z][a-z][a-z] [0-9][0-9] [0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]%', rest) + 11,
                    11),
              lev + 1
      from cte
      where rest like '%[A-Z][a-z][a-z] [0-9][0-9] [0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]%' and lev < 5
     )
select id, dte
from cte
where lev > 0;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=62caa88d26035efd325c7b682abc16ec) is a db<>fiddle.

Answer (score 3):

This is a similar approach to Gordon, but using the expression in the `FROM` and the `WHERE` clauses within the rCTE:

```sql
WITH YourTable AS(
    SELECT *
    FROM (VALUES(2,'This value is Nov 20 2020 and will be Jan 20 2021'),
                (3,'This value is Sep 20 2020 and will be Oct 20 2020, Nov 20 2020'))V(ID,TextString)),
rCTE AS(
    SELECT YT.ID,
           CONVERT(varchar(4000),YT.TextString) AS TextString,
           V.I AS PatStart,
           CONVERT(varchar(4000),SUBSTRING(YT.TextString,V.I,11)) AS DateString
    FROM YourTable YT
         CROSS APPLY(VALUES(PATINDEX('%[A-z][A-z][A-z] [0-9][0-9] [0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]%',YT.TextString)))V(I)
    WHERE V.I > 0
    UNION ALL
    SELECT r.ID,
           CONVERT(varchar(4000),S.TextString) AS TextString,
           V.I AS PatStart,
           CONVERT(varchar(4000),SUBSTRING(S.TextString,V.I,11)) AS DateString
    FROM rCTE r
         CROSS APPLY (VALUES(STUFF(r.TextString,1,r.PatStart+11,'')))S(TextString)
         CROSS APPLY(VALUES(PATINDEX('%[A-z][A-z][A-z] [0-9][0-9] [0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]%',S.TextString)))V(I)
    WHERE V.I > 0)
SELECT r.Id,
       TRY_CONVERT(date,r.DateString,109) AS YourDate
FROM rCTE r;
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a combination of approaches and it uses the ordinal splitter [DelimitedSplit8K](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/tally-oh-an-improved-sql-8k-%E2%80%9Ccsv-splitter%E2%80%9D-function).

Data

```
drop table if exists dbo.tTable;
go
create table dbo.tTable(
  [Text]                varchar(100) not null,
  id                    int not null);

insert dbo.tTable values
('This value is Nov 20 2020 and will be Jan 20 2021',1),
('This value is Sep 20 2020 and will be Oct 20 2020, Nov 20 2020',2);
```

Query

```
;with split_cte(id, split, split_num, rn, sumlen) as (
    select id, Item, ItemNumber, 
           row_number() over (partition by id order by  ItemNumber), 
           sum(len(Item)) over (partition by id order by ItemNumber) 
    from tTable t 
         cross apply dbo.DelimitedSplit8K(t.[Text], ' '))
select t.id, extract_dt.dt
from tTable t
     join split_cte sc on t.id=sc.id
     join (values('Jan'), ('Feb'), ('Mar'), ('Apr'),
                 ('May'), ('Jun'), ('Jul'), ('Aug'),
                 ('Sep'), ('Oct'), ('Nov'), ('Dec')) m(Name) on sc.split=m.Name
     cross apply
     (select substring(t.[Text], sc.sumlen + (rn-3), 11) dt) extract_dt;
```

Output

```
id  dt
1   Nov 20 2020
1   Jan 20 2021
2   Sep 20 2020
2   Oct 20 2020
2   Nov 20 2020
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to create a user-defined CLR function to expose regex functionality. You write a .NET code, load it on the server and use as SQL code.

It might be better to just have regex function in .NET rather than having the whole logic in the assembly.

To return first occurrence you'll have to write [Scalar-Valued Function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/clr-integration-database-objects-user-defined-functions/clr-scalar-valued-functions?view=sql-server-ver15). Here's an example:

```
using System.Data.SqlTypes;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

[Microsoft.SqlServer.Server.SqlFunction(IsDeterministic = true)]
public static SqlString Match(String input, String pattern)
{
    Match m = Regex.Match(input, pattern);
    return new SqlString(m.Success ? m.Value : null);
}
```

To return all occurrences you'll have to write [Table-Valued Function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/clr-integration-database-objects-user-defined-functions/clr-table-valued-functions?view=sql-server-ver15). Here's an example:

```
[SqlFunction(DataAccess = DataAccessKind.None, FillRowMethodName = "FillMatches", TableDefinition = "MatchText nvarchar(max)")]
public static IEnumerable Matches(String input, String pattern)
{
    List<RegexMatch> MatchCollection = new List<RegexMatch>();
    foreach (Match m in Regex.Matches(input, pattern))
    {
        MatchCollection.Add(m.Value);
    }
    return MatchCollection;
}

private class RegexMatch
{
    public SqlString MatchText { get; set; }

    public RegexMatch(SqlString match)
    {
        this.MatchText = match;
    }
}

public static void FillMatches(object match, out SqlString MatchText)
{
    MatchText = (String)match;
}
```

[docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/clr-integration-database-objects-user-defined-functions/clr-user-defined-functions?view=sql-server-ver15)